Docstring shows twice in pycharm
I have a Python class with methods that include docstrings. When I hover over the method names in my IDE (I'm using PyCharm), the docstring content appears twice. Here's an example of one of my methods:
import numpy as np

class ReLu:
    """
    ReLu (Rectified Linear Unit) activation function for neural networks.
    """

    def forward_train(self, z: np.array) -> np.array:
                """
    Perform the forward pass during training and store the input for use in backpropagation.

    Args:
        z (np.array): The input data to the activation function.

    Returns:
        np.array: The result of applying the ReLU function to the input data.
    """
        self.__z = z
        return self.forward(z)

Problem:
When I hover over the forward_train method in PyCharm, I see the text twice, like this:
    Perform the forward pass during training and store the input for use in backpropagation.  
Args: z (np. array): The input data to the activation function.  Returns: np. array: The result of applying the ReLU function to the input data.
    Params:
    z – The input data to the activation function.
    Returns:
    The result of applying the ReLU function to the input data.

It looks like the IDE is displaying my docstring twice, formatted differently. I want to know how to avoid this duplication or what might be causing it.

That's not the conventional layout for a docstring, which may be confusing things: https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/

It's not showing the whole docstring twice. It's extracting the parameter and return information from the docstring and showing those details in addition to the docstring.

@Barmar that may be. But is there a possibility to show it only once in PyCharm.

I don't have PyCharm, but I have PhpStorm. There's a preferences checkbox for "Show quick documentation on hover", but nothing to customize the format of the quick documentation as far as I can tell.
